# Полоса прокрутки у таблицы

Tags: html, css

Есть PHP код: `<?php echo file_get_contents(...); ?>`. Он выводит на страницу следующее:

```
<table style="width: 2000px;">
    ...
</table>
```

Из-за этой таблицы страница расширяется. Как сделать так, чтобы страница не расширялась, то есть сделать ширину отображаемого фрагмента, например, `600px` и внизу у таблицы сделать полосу прокрутки? Саму таблицу сжимать нельзя, ширина и высота её строчек и столбцов не должны измениться.

---

Как должно быть:

[image: Как должно быть]

Как получается:

[image: Как получается]

Это примерные скриншоты на обычной таблице.

Comment: Задать у контейнера фиксированную ширину (`width: 600px`) и сделать `overflow: scroll`.

Comment: Думаю вы это знаете и ваш дизайн чем-то обоснован, но все же напомню, что горизонтальная прокрутка не приветствуется в web-дизайне :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно задать у контейнера фиксированную ширину (`width: 600px`) и сделать `overflow: scroll`:

```css
table {
    width: 2000px;
}

td {
    border: solid 1px;
}

.container {
    width: 600px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```css
table {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>123456789012345678901234567890
    <td>123456789012345678901234567890
    <td>123456789012345678901234567890
    <td>123456789012345678901234567890
    <td>123456789012345678901234567890
    <td>123456789012345678901234567890
    <td>123456789012345678901234567890
    <td>123456789012345678901234567890
    <td>123456789012345678901234567890
    <td>123456789012345678901234567890
    <td>123456789012345678901234567890
    <td>123456789012345678901234567890
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>123456789012345678901234567890
    <td>123456789012345678901234567890
    <td>123456789012345678901234567890
    <td>123456789012345678901234567890
    <td>123456789012345678901234567890
    <td>123456789012345678901234567890
    <td>123456789012345678901234567890
    <td>123456789012345678901234567890
    <td>123456789012345678901234567890
    <td>123456789012345678901234567890
    <td>123456789012345678901234567890
    <td>123456789012345678901234567890
  </tr>
</table>
```